# count the number of rows between intervals

Tags: mysql

My table is like:

```
+---------+---------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| visitId | userId  | locationId | comments              | time                |
+---------+---------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
|       1 |    3    |     12     | It's a good day here! | 2012-12-12 11:50:12 |
+---------+---------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
|       2 |    3    |     23     | very beautiful        | 2012-12-12 12:50:12 |
+---------+---------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
|       3 |    3    |     52     | nice                  | 2012-12-12 13:50:12 |
+---------+---------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

which records **visitors' trajectory and some comments on the places visited**.

I want to count the numbers of visitors that visit a specific place (say id=3227) from 0:00 to 23:59, over some interval (ie. 30mins)

**I was trying to do this** by :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visits 
GROUP BY HOUR(time), SIGN( MINUTE(time) - 30 )// if they are in the same interval this will yield the same result
WHERE locationId=3227
```

**The problem is that** if there is no record that falls in some interval, this will NOT return that interval with count 0. For example, there are no visitors visiting the location from 02:00 to 03:00, this will not give me the intervals of 02:00-02:29 and 02:30-2:59.

**I want a result with an exact size of 48** (one for every half hour), how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a table with the 48 rows that you want and use left outer join:

```
select n.hr, n.hr, coalesce(v.cnt, 0) as cnt
from (select 0 as hr, -1 as sign union all
      select 0, 1 union all
      select 1, -1 union all
      select 1, 1 union all
      . . .
      select 23, -1 union all
      select 23, 1 union all
     ) left outer join
     (SELECT HOUR(time) as hr, SIGN( MINUTE(time) - 30 ) as sign, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM visits 
      WHERE locationId=3227
      GROUP BY HOUR(time), SIGN( MINUTE(time) - 30 )
     ) v
     on n.hr = v.hr and n.sign = v.sign
order by n.hr, n.hr
```

Comment: this works, but it's suffering to type in such a long statement..thanks!